# Trim a string to get date in middle?

Tags: c#

I need the following string trimmed

```
Sat, 02/04/1708:00 PM
```

so that the result is 02/04/17

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Regex rg = new Regex(@"[01]?\d[/-][0123]?\d[/-]\d{2}");
 Match m = rg.Match("Sat, 02/04/1708:00 PM");
 Console.Write(m.ToString());
```

**[`WORKING FIDDLE`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EwmHKe)**

Comment: @user7392548 Check the sample

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var str = @"Sat, 02/04/1708:00 PM";
var res = str.Split(' ')[1].Substring(0, 8);
```

Comment: Which will give you `02/04/1708:00 PM` not `02/04/1708` as he expecting

Comment: I need 02/04/17

Comment: @un-lucky ok, you right, corrected

Comment: @user7392548 you get it with this simple code

Answer (score 0):

you can use **substring**

`string str="Sat, 02/04/1708:00 PM";`

`string newStr=str.Substring(5,8);`

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = @"Sat, 02/04/1708:00 PM";
String expected = str.split(' ')[1].Substring(0,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
string strInput = @"Sat, 02/04/1708:00 PM";
var dateResult = strInput.Split(' ', ',')[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you.

```
string smdt = "Sun, 02/04/1708:00 PM";
string format = "ddd, dd/MM/yyhh:mm tt";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(smdt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None);
string extractedDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```

The problem with the Question was the Date `02/04/17` is not a `Saturday` instead it will be `Sunday` and thus it will not be able to convert to a `DateTime`. When I change `Sat to Sun`. The `extractedDate` is the result which you are looking for.

One liner answer could be

```
string smdt = "Sun, 02/04/1708:00 PM";
string extractedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                                                smdt, 
                                                "ddd, dd/MM/yyhh:mm tt", 
                                                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                                DateTimeStyles.None
                                           ).ToString("dd/MM/yy");
```