# Add AM/PM To Time

Tags: c#, string.format

My `datetime` is in this format `2017-01-15T21:00-07:00` so I am parsing it out like so

```
string ADT = Convert.ToString(timestamp.DateOrTimestamp);
int index = ADT.IndexOf("T");
string FADT = (index > 0 ? ADT.Substring(0, index) : "");
DateTime dtFADT = DateTime.ParseExact(FADT, "yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string ADT1 = ADT.Split('T', '-')[3];

Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", timestamp.Type, dtFADT.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " " + String.Format("{0:h:mm t}", ADT1));
```

Which will write to the console: `Delivery: 01/15/2017 09:00:00`

**Why** does the `String.Format()` not add in the AM/PM to my time?

Comment: `21:00-07:00` is this a range or what? If `07` is for seconds, then what does the last `00` means?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7875259/how-do-i-get-the-am-pm-value-from-a-datetime
and also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13044603/convert-time-span-value-to-format-hhmm-am-pm-using-c-sharp

Comment: Your `DateTime` is **NOT** in the format `2017-01-15T21:00-07:00`. That is a `string`. `DateTime` does **NOT** have a format - it's just a number. It's only when you call `.ToString(...)` that you create a `string` that has a format.

Comment: @Enigmativity - sorry for not properly understanding DateTime vs String when it comes to a DateTime or String.  How about an applicable example of remedying my issue and not a tongue lashing or lesson on variables.

Comment: You can have a look at [ParseExact](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41606677/3796048) and look for `format` you can also set accordingly for you.

Comment: @Ghasan - no it is in a String Format (not sure why they call it DateOrTimestamp if it is string)

Comment: @MohitShrivastava - that got it.  If you put as answer I accept.

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights Have a look at the updated answer. :)

Comment: @StarsFlyFreeFromCozyNights - Sorry, there was no tongue lashing. Just trying to be very clear about the relationship between `DateTime` and date/time formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
string smdt = "2017-01-15T21:00-07:00";
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mmzzz";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(smdt, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
string extractedDate = dt.ToString("dd/MM/yy h:mm tt");
```

Comment: Still no am/pm added in

Comment: I don't understand what you are after?

Comment: Does not work correctly depending on configured system time format. In windows you can configure this here: (Control Panel | Language | Change date, time or number formats | Additional settings... | Time)
see AM and PM symbol Time formats.
I kept getting a.m rather than AM

Answer (score 0):

To do something similar I ended up having to make a CultureInfo based off eu-US but with the 2nd argument set to false to not allow system / user over-rides of the formats.

```
public static CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);
```

Then I could use it in code anywhere I needed to format a date for parsing or toString with a date/time having the **tt** part of the format it would put the AM or PM that I wanted.

The system language setting on the PC the software was running on was different to mine. They used a.m or Pm or something like that. when we wanted to use AM or PM.